# Rocket Engine Plume/Exhaust

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am totally new a pictures and blender therefore I dont know how to ask. I want to add rocket plume but I am not interested with animation. I need to add like texture.

[image: Model of Engine.]

Reference image:

[image: You can see the plume over the rocket engine.]

Comment: Could you post some reference image to show us what you want to achieve?